# php file_get_contents not working in linux hosting for asmx link

Tags: php, linux, web-services, webserver, hosting

My piece of code is as below:

```
$CheckingLink="http://1.2.3.4:8080/abc.asmx/GetStatus?MobileNo=$MobileNO";
$CheckStatus=file_get_contents($CheckingLink);
if($CheckStatus==1)
  return true;
```

It's working properly in my local PC and return value 1. 
But when i upload this same code into my linux hosting then the link is not returning anything.
On the other hand, if i try any php link like "`http://1.2.3.4:8080/abc.php?MobileNo=$MobileNO`"
it's working properly on my pc as well as hosting.

My pc & hosting configuration parameters are as below:

My pc:

```
OS: Winwods8
Webserver: IIS8
PHP version: 5.4.24
```

Hosting server:

```
OS: Linux
Webserver: apache 2.2.29
PHP Version: 5.2.17
```

Did not get any solution on searching over the internet. Waiting for a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of 'allow_url_fopen' parameter into php.ini.
If value of 'allow_url_fopen' is either false or 0 then it will not allow you to use file_get_contents with url.

You can set the value of 'allow_url_fopen = 1' in php.ini.

Comment: i don't have the access on my hosting's php.ini. is there any other way to do it?

Comment: print phpinfo() on a test file and check the output

Comment: Yes, you can use following method :- ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1)

Comment: i have set the ini_set. but no improvement. same as previous.